# Trying to figure out what the command mean

Tags: command-line, pipe

Please explain me what does this command mean:

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

1. `wget` - use wget to download something
2. `-qO-`  first argument is -q, but what does `0-` mean? why does it have dash after it?
3. `| sh` - something about pipe, but what exactly?

Yes, I read man wget.

Comment: Should `-q0-` be written as `-q -0 -`? What is the correct way?

Comment: Either `-qO-` or `-q -O -` is correct, because they both mean the same thing. All the flags that start with a hyphen character can be grouped together as a single multiple flag that also starts with a hyphen. Example: `tar -xzvf archive.tar.gz` is the same command as `tar -x -z -v -f archive.tar.gz` and it is also better visually organized.

Comment: @DKBose That is not `0`, that's `O`. And for your question: It depends. If a command wants an argument after it, you can't type for example `-q -i` after each. Let's make a real example: try this: `wget -ci file` and `wget -ic links.txt`. First is read as this: "Download and continue from the `link.txt` input file (-i is for input-file)" , but the second is read like this:"Download from file `c` (because the c is exactly after -i, and it thinks that the input file name is `c`) and throws an error. Let me know if you need more examples.

Answer (score 2):

`-q` runs wget in quiet mode.

```
 -O file
       --output-document=file
           The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
           will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
           file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
           conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)
```

`sh` is the Bourne shell. There are several shells, of which Bourne is the old standard.

Your command above is saying to run `wget` in quiet mode (`-q`) and because output (`O`) takes `-`, instead of providing a file as destination, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion. Then the use of pipe `|` starts `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

```
-q
      --quiet
          Turn off Wget's output.

-O file
      --output-document=file
          The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
          will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
          file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
          conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)

sh
      The shell is a command that reads lines from either a file or the terminal,
      interprets them, and generally executes other commands.
```

The vertical line pipe character before the sh pipes the output from `-O-` (standard output to the terminal) to the `sh` command which says to execute the file that was downloaded in the terminal as a program, assuming that the file that was downloaded first has its permissions set to allow executing the file as a program.

To set the permissions to allow executing a file as a program: right-click the file, select *Properties* to open the Properties popup window and in *Properties* select the Permissions tab,and put a check mark to the left of where it says: *Allow executing file as program*.

Answer (score 1):

```
* wget:     The non-interactive network downloader

* -q (--quit):    Turn off Wget's output.

* -O file (--output-document=file):    The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.  

* URL https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh     wget [option]... [URL]...

* | Pipelines
    A  pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&.  The
    format for a pipeline is:

           [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]

    The standard output of command is connected  via  a  pipe  to  the  standard  input  of  command2.


* sh  command interpreter (shell)
```

In overall this command will just download the script called install-ubuntu.sh from the given URL and then pass to the pipeline to be as input to the next comand which is sh. Thus this will install and run the script called install-ubuntu.sh in single command.